# Find $W_1,W_2\neq \mathbb R^2$ so that $U+W_1=U+W_2=\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

in the vector space $ \mathbb R_{col}^{2} $, there's a vector subspace $U=\mathbb R  w$, and $$ w=\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}\right] $$ find two different vector subspace $W_1,W_2\neq \mathbb R_{col}^{2}$ so that:
$$ U+W_1=U+W_2=\mathbb R_{col}^{2}$$

Comment: How about $\begin{bmatrix}{1\\0}\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: I don't get what would that work as a solution

Comment: @Mr787: Try a bit harder to verify that the hint given by JWTanner will work.

Comment: You can literally pick any three (distinct) 1D subspaces.

Comment: Like $\mathbb R \cdot \begin{bmatrix}{1\\0}\end{bmatrix}$ as $W_1$?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget the definition $U+W_1=\{u+w_1\mid u\in U,\ w_1\in W_1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$W_1=\{(x,0): x\in \mathbb{R}\} \\
 W_2=\{(0,y):y\in \mathbb{R}\} \\
U=\{(x,y): x,y\in \mathbb{R}\textrm{ and }y=x\}$$.

Comment: Did you mean $y=\color{red}-x$?